# How to get access to back button in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can you please clarify me, what's the best practice for this example:

**Activity1** does INSERTS on SQLite and starts Activity2.

**On Activity2**, the user clicks on Back button and goes back to Activity1.
But instead of making INSERT, I want to make UPDATE to the data on SQLite.

**How do I control, that user "came" back?**

**What's the best practice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume on button click you starting Activity 2

```
public static final int YOURCONSTANTNUMBER = 77;
   //Button Value
 Button second = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
 second.setOnClickListner(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
  switch(v.getId())
   {
      case R.id.btnSecondActivity:
      //Code for inserting data into database
      Intent secondactivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(secondactivity);
      break;
    }
}
```

**In your second activity**

To take control over the back button use the below code

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {      
//Code for update     
 }
```

**EDIT**

Call your second activity with `startActivityForResult()` method which will let you know the result.

**In First Activity**

```
    Intent secondactivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(secondactivity,YOURCONSTANTNUMBER);
```

Getting Result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   
 switch(requestCode)
 {
 case YOURCONSTANTNUMBER:
     // It will execute if you returning from second activity 
     //Update you database here
     }
 }
```

**In Your Second Activity**

Call this method were appropriate `setResult(YOURCONSTANTNUMBER);`

Hope it helps

Comment: How do I know on Activity1, that user came from Activity2? To know if I should make a insert or an update?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do both DB operations in Activity1, consider startActivityForResult() here:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)